# Displaying the objects from my class on the base template in Django

Tags: django

Sorry if my english is confusing

I created a class **Button** on my app **menu**

**models.py (App 'menu')**

```
from django.db import models

class Button(models.Model):
    button_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name='xxx')
    button_dirurl = models.CharField(max_length=40, verbose_name='xxx')
    button_corequise = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='xxx')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.button_name
```

What I would like to do is to display all the objects into **base.html**, located into the **template** at the **root**.

I tried to do a tag, but I would like to add some html elements and as far as it goes I won't be able to do much

**menu_tags.py (App 'menu')**

```
from django import template
from menu.models import Button

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def show_menu():
    a = Button.objects.all()
    return a
```

I'm sorry if this was already asked but I don't know how to google this as my english is quite bad. Thanks !

Comment: I don't understand what is wrong with using a tag. What do you mean, you won't be able to do much?

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for [inclusion tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags). You can render a template that loops through the buttons.

Comment: Well, what should I put into the brackets if I use inclusion tags ?

Comment: I don't understand. What should you put into which bracket? Have a go at creating an inclusion tag. If you get stuck, update your question with what you tried.

Comment: Ok, I tried and it's working fine. I would also like to call the ID of the button, but how to do it ?